# IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`)

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I understand that there are a lot of answers on this topic but I have scrutinized all of them and did not find something suitable for me.
I'm sure that error is childish but still can not find a solution.
I want to take some element from `numpy.linspace`.

```
 import numpy
 #Porosity range
 phi = numpy.linspace(0.1, 1, num=10)
 mu = [1, 10, 100, 1000]
```

Example for how it looks like but not in loop and it works:

```
 mu_total3 = mu[0]*phi[2]+ mu[1]*(1 - phi[2])
 print(mu_total3)
 7.3
```

What I want in following:

```
 for x in phi:
      mu_total = mu[0]*phi[x]+ mu[1]*(1 - phi[x])
      print(mu_total)
```

Comment: When you do `for x in phi:`, what does `x` look like?  What do you expect it to be?  Can you justify using `phi[x]`?  In the original you use `phi[2]`.  Why the change?

Comment: I think what you want is either `for i in len(phi): mu[0]*phi[i]+...` or `for p in phi: mu[0]*p+...`.

Comment: You need to review the basics of Python iteration.  `for i in ['a','b','c']: print(i)`.  The iteration variable is an element of the source list (or array); it isn't an index or counter.

Comment: @ThomasKühn thanks, I solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is specialised at doing vector operations. That is taking an one or two arrays and applying an operation to all its elements. For python lists you might write:

```
zs = [] 
for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
    z = x + 2*y
    zs.append(z)
print(zs)
```

Wheras with a numpy array you can write:

```
zs = xs + 2*ys
print(zs)
```

Applied to your code that becomes:

```
mu_totals = mu[0]*phi + mu[1]*(1 - phi)
```